how to set the colour of inner request body colour to my default dark colour in redocly?
I'm using redocly for my api documentation. Currently I'm having an issue when I using the dark mode, the inner schemas of a request body appears in a white background. I want to change it to dark colour.

As you can see if I edit the background colour of the class sc-ikkxIA daqcVd then it will fix my issue. Since it is a random generated class i wanted to know how we can solve this issue permanently.

Are the td containing only schemas ? And to what extent the class names are randomly generated ?
If the td only contains schemas and the class names always start with "sc", you could target the div by doing :
td div[class^="sc-"] {
   background-color: /* the color you want */
}

By doing so you will provide the background color for every div that have a td parents and have a class name starting with "sc-".
